# VBA time filter with user input

Tags: vba, excel

I have the next VBA code that know how to filter between two date range:

```
Public Sub MyFilter()
    Dim lngStart As Date, lngEnd As Date
    lngStart = Range("b2").Value 'assume this is the start date
    lngEnd = Range("b3").Value 'assume this is the end date
    Range("A5:T5").AutoFilter Field:=17, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd


End Sub
```

I wonder how can I modify it to be more user friendly and to update it accordantly:
 1. end time can be always current time.
 2. I wish that at start time cell I will able to enter numbers such as: 4,5,9 and code will know to modify it to "current date -4 hours" instead of let me enter full date string.

Any idea how can I edit it?, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, so I'm guessing a bit.
Have a look at this:

```
Public Sub MyFilter()
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date

    StartDate = DateAdd("h", -Range("b2"), Now)
    EndDate = Now

    Range("A5:T5").AutoFilter Field:=17, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate

End Sub
```

I have replaced the end date value with `Now`, which gives current time. Depending on your needs, you might need to adjust it to midnight of today or yesterday. The start date is now calculated with `DateAdd`. The number of hours are picked up from B2 and subtracted from `Now`.

btw - you need to rethink your variable naming. Prefixing dates with lng is not good practice

Comment: Hi, Thanks that what I searched for..
I do have two more short questions that I forget to mention.
1. if I have blank cells under the same column how can I get them too?
2. if I want my ending time will be always 08:00am on the same date I open the file, how can I modify the code? thanks!!!

Comment: 1. I don't understand. 2. Replace with `EndDate = DateAdd("h","8",Date)`

Comment: regarding 1. I have more cells in the same column with "null" data (empty cells) I want to retrieve them too.

Comment: That I understood. I didn't get what you wanted to do with them

Comment: empty cells = "(blank)" -- how its appears at Excel

Comment: Retrieve them too... all cells that applied to filter range + all cells with no data (blank).

Comment: To solve that, I would recommend an advanced filter instead of auto filter. We are leaving the original question too much now, so I suggest that you look into what you can do with Advanced filters and post a new question if needed.